# Admob ad slides down the screen

Tags: android, admob

I created a 5 relative layout inside a scroll view and I make that count 6 with the Admob ad. The problem is Admob ad is the 3rd layout. When I open that screen the app slides down itself to the ad.Because it is not seen when the screen opened.

What I want to do is, if user slides down the screen, he/she can see the ad, otherwise not. Is it possible? Also I heard that what I made is not allowed. How can I fix it?

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ahmetbesli.eczanem.ListedPharmacies">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#243451"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/list"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/relative0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView0" />

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/textView0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_list"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        android:id="@+id/relative1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_list"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </RelativeLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/relative2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeBanner"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_list"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/relative3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_list"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/relative4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_list"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeBanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"> 
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
            ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your ad to be there when user slides down (if that's what you are asking) Simply use the adListeners and play with the layouts visibility. Visible when ad is loaded and visibility gone when ad fails to load.

```
AdLoader adLoader = builder.withAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            relativeBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            relativeBanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }


    }).build();
```